# PyQt5, adding text to tabs doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I am making an IDE in python and I've had some trouble adding text to my tabs.

Adding the title works but adding the text inside of it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import json
from pyautogui import hotkey
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QRegExp, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QFont, QPainter,
                         QSyntaxHighlighter, QTextCharFormat, QTextCursor)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QDialog, QFileDialog, QPushButton,
                             QHBoxLayout, QInputDialog, QMainWindow,
                             QMessageBox, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTabWidget,
                             qApp, QMenuBar, QStatusBar)

lineBarColor = QColor(53, 53, 53)
lineHighlightColor = QColor('#00FF04')


class NumberBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.editor = parent
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.editor.blockCountChanged.connect(self.update_width)
        self.editor.updateRequest.connect(self.update_on_scroll)
        self.update_width('1')

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print("class NumberBar(QWidget):mousePressEvent")

    def update_on_scroll(self, rect, scroll):
        if self.isVisible():
            if scroll:
                self.scroll(0, scroll)
            else:
                self.update()

    def update_width(self, string):
        width = self.fontMetrics().width(str(string)) + 10
        print("update_width:width:" + str(width))
        if self.width() != width:
            self.setFixedWidth(width)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            block = self.editor.firstVisibleBlock()
            height = self.fontMetrics().height()
            number = block.blockNumber()
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.fillRect(event.rect(), lineBarColor)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, event.rect().width() - 1, event.rect().height() - 1)
            font = painter.font()

            current_block = self.editor.textCursor().block().blockNumber() + 1

            while block.isValid():
                block_geometry = self.editor.blockBoundingGeometry(block)
                offset = self.editor.contentOffset()
                block_top = block_geometry.translated(offset).top()
                number += 1

                rect = QRect(0, block_top, self.width() - 5, height)

                if number == current_block:
                    font.setBold(True)
                else:
                    font.setBold(False)

                painter.setFont(font)
                painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignRight, '%i' % number)

                if block_top > event.rect().bottom():
                    break

                block = block.next()

            painter.end()


class Content(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Content, self).__init__()
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        # Create a layout for the line numbers

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.numbers = NumberBar(self.editor)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.numbers)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.editor)


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def addtab(self, content, fileName):
        self.tabs.addTab(Content(str(content)), str(fileName))


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.open()

        self.tabs = MyTableWidget(self)
        #self.tabs.addtab("nga", "sa")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()
        menu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)

        self.resize(800, 600)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.tabs.addTab(Content("smalltext2"), "sadsad")

    def open(self):
        self.openAct = QAction('Open...', self)
        self.openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.openAct.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        self.is_opened = False
        self.openAct.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        self.files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 'Open a file', '',
            'All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)',
            options=options
        )

        self.files = self.files[0]
        if self.files:
            with open(self.files, 'r+') as file_o:
                print(self.files)
                text = file_o.read()
                text_widget = QPlainTextEdit(self.tabs)
                text_widget.setPlainText(text)
                self.tabs.addtab(text_widget, self.files[0])
                print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("../config.json", "r") as jsonFile:
        read = jsonFile.read()
        data = json.loads(read)
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle('Fusion')
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QColor(data["editor"][0]["windowColor"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QColor(data["editor"][0]["windowText"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QColor(data["editor"][0]["editorColor"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(data["editor"][0]["alternateBase"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, QColor(data["editor"][0]["ToolTipBase"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, QColor(data["editor"][0]["ToolTipText"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QColor(data["editor"][0]["editorText"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QColor(data["editor"][0]["buttonColor"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(data["editor"][0]["buttonTextColor"]))
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QColor(data["editor"][0]["HighlightColor"]).lighter())
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QColor(data["editor"][0]["HighlightedTextColor"]))
        app.setPalette(palette)
        ex = Main()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the line 171 I'm trying to add a tab with the contents of the file I opened `self.tabs.addtab(text_widget, self.files[0])`.

It does create the tab with the name `self.files[0]` but the content isn't inside of there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really simple, you are creating many `QPlainTextEdit`s unnecessarily, for example there is a `QPlainTextEdit` in `openFile()` method that you pass to the method `addtab()`, but if you check the method `addtab()` `MyTableWidget` requires a string and not the `QPlainTextEdit`, There is another `QPlainTextEdit` in `MyTableWidget` unnecessarily.

Eliminating the unnecessary elements we obtain the following:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, \
    QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QFileDialog, QPlainTextEdit, QHBoxLayout


lineBarColor = QColor(53, 53, 53)
lineHighlightColor = QColor('#00FF04')


class NumberBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = parent
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.editor.blockCountChanged.connect(self.update_width)
        self.editor.updateRequest.connect(self.update_on_scroll)
        self.update_width('1')

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print("class NumberBar(QWidget):mousePressEvent")

    def update_on_scroll(self, rect, scroll):
        if self.isVisible():
            if scroll:
                self.scroll(0, scroll)
            else:
                self.update()

    def update_width(self, string):
        width = self.fontMetrics().width(str(string)) + 10
        print("update_width:width:" + str(width))
        if self.width() != width:
            self.setFixedWidth(width)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            block = self.editor.firstVisibleBlock()
            height = self.fontMetrics().height()
            number = block.blockNumber()
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.fillRect(event.rect(), lineBarColor)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, event.rect().width() - 1, event.rect().height() - 1)
            font = painter.font()

            current_block = self.editor.textCursor().block().blockNumber() + 1

            while block.isValid():
                block_geometry = self.editor.blockBoundingGeometry(block)
                offset = self.editor.contentOffset()
                block_top = block_geometry.translated(offset).top()
                number += 1

                rect = QRect(0, block_top, self.width() - 5, height)

                if number == current_block:
                    font.setBold(True)
                else:
                    font.setBold(False)

                painter.setFont(font)
                painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignRight, '%i' % number)

                if block_top > event.rect().bottom():
                    break

                block = block.next()

            painter.end()


class Content(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Content, self).__init__()
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editor.setPlainText(text)
        # Create a layout for the line numbers

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.numbers = NumberBar(self.editor)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.numbers)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.editor)


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def addtab(self, content, fileName):
        self.tabs.addTab(Content(str(content)), str(fileName))


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.open()

        self.tabs = MyTableWidget()
        #self.tabs.addtab("nga", "sa")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()
        menu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)

        self.resize(800, 600)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.tabs.addTab(Content("smalltext2"), "sadsad")

    def open(self):
        self.openAct = QAction('Open...', self)
        self.openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.openAct.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        self.is_opened = False
        self.openAct.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        filenames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 'Open a file', '',
            'All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)',
            options=options
        )
        if filenames:
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename, 'r+') as file_o:
                    text = file_o.read()
                    self.tabs.addtab(text, filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```